# Translate checkout text input fields

Tags: magento-2.1.4

How to translate checkout label text?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look into

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n
```

directory to find the text

Now extend this file by copying  from

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n folder to app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n
```

directory.

Here you can find the text and change as per your need.

Remove content from

```
/var/cache folder and /var/page_cache.

Run upgrade/deploy/cache
```

commands as well if you don't see the changes.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: I did exactly what you have told me, but nothing happens? https://ibb.co/nc7oSv

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy.

In Magento 2, just go to website control panel/admin.
Then click `Store > Configuration`.
Then click `Advanced > Developer > Translate Inline`.
Select `yes` in `Enabled for Storefront` drop down and then click "Save Config" button.
[image]

Then refresh the page in front-end. Here you can see one book icon when you will hover the label. Click this book icon. Here you can change this label translation. 
[image]

**Note: Same settings are available in Magento 1**

Comment: Input fields are not translatable https://ibb.co/kMRbEa

Comment: Every text is translatable

Comment: Please check my screenshot: https://ibb.co/kMRbEa

Comment: It means you just type simple text in template file. You should use $block->escapeHtml(__('Label'));

Comment: Please check my proplem, i tryed but not translate error message validate required " this is a required field. " https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278178/how-to-translate-this-is-a-required-in-magento-2