# How to override text using block in whole magento 2...actually i want to override cart with bucket.....?

Tags: magento2

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

actully i am trying this link below here..
https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/

Comment: could you provide more detail about your question, do you mean you want to change text from cart to Bucket ?

Comment: i want to replace cart text to bucket text in whole magento2

Answer (score 0):

To change text or translation you don't need to create module only you have to do is find the related module language file and change text there, i.e

for example to change cart text you have to change language file of checkout module. so if your store language is en_US ( English United States ) then you have to change.

How to do it :
check this post [Change label text](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184093/translate-checkout-text-input-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Create csv named **en_US.csv** under below path

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n

and add the below line to it.

```
Cart,Bucket

My cart, My bucket
```

etc

If you are using different language then change the csv name according to that.

Comment: do you any idea,how to change delete alert text and when cart is empty then also this method not working....