# How to translate " This is a required " in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, validation, required

I want translate error message required field like this

[image]

I used de_DE.csv but the get fields from data it does not translate, please help me! Thanks all

Comment: you can refer to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269056/translation-file-magento-2-i18n?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: thank you fmsthird. i tryed but it not translate only field get by data

Comment: which specific Magento version do you use?

Comment: Hi Fmsthrid, i using Magento Edition: Community - Version: 2.3

Comment: can you include your language locale settings?

Comment: yes, i can translate all, but can't not translate only input field get from database

Comment: did you find this before https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21204

Comment: yes bro, i tryed it but not translate